# vector adds CSV column data into vector rows while transfering CSV file's data into c++ vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to add CSV file into a 2D array vector i.e: vector of vector. The following program works well but there is a small problem,

For example to add the following CSV data:

```
1.4,23.44,24.4,3.0
2.3,4.3,44.5,6.6
3.4,33.2,5.4,3.65
```

i have used the following code:

```
void Table::addTableData(string filename)
    vector<vector<float> > vec;

        ifstream file(filename.c_str());


            bool first = false;
            if (file)
            {
                string line;

                while (getline(file,line)) //reading the data line by line
                {
                    istringstream split(line);
                    float value;
                    int col = 0;
                    char sep;

                while (split >> value) //
                {
                    if(!first)
                    {
                        // Each new value read on line 1 should create a new inner vector
                        vec.push_back(std::vector<float>());
                    }

                    vec[col].push_back(value);
                    ++col;

                    // read past the separator
                    split>>sep;
                }

                // Finished reading line 1 and creating as many inner
                // vectors as required
                first = true;
            }
```

However, The above code executes and adds data into the vector, but rather than adding each value in the first line in inner vector it adds the column as a row in the inner vector. I mean to say the rows and column in the CSV file becomes column and rows in the vector respectively. If I do a cout then I get the following result

```
1.4 2.3 3.4
23.44 4.3 33.2
24.4 44.5 5.4 
3.0 6.6 3.65
```

Therefore. the row and column is reversed, How do I turn things around.

Thank you for looking at this probelm.

Comment: Your use of `vec[col]` strongly suggests that `vec` was intended to be a vector of columns, not a vector of rows. Is this not what you want? The code appears to be very deliberately written to produce precisely the outcome you observe - it doesn't seem to have happened by accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add each row into a vector, and then push it back, instead of adding to each vector each time:

```
while (getline(file,line)) //reading the data line by line
{
    std::vector<float> nextRow;

    // etc.
    while (split >> value)
    {
        nextRow.push_back(value);
        split >> sep;
    }

    vec.push_back(nextRow);
}
```

Comment: It worked but it doesn't read the data after the ","  the above code reads the first column and discards the other column after the comma sign.

Comment: @DeepeshThapa was meant to just illustrate the idea, not be a complete solution. Added the bit reading the comma.

Comment: i figured it out.. just need to add the  split>>sep; at end of the while loop.. thank you it works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Table::addTableData(string filename)
```

{
    vector > vec;

```
ifstream file(filename.c_str());

bool first = false;
if (file)
{
    string line;
    int col = 0;
    while (getline(file,line)) //reading the data line by line
    {
        istringstream split(line);
        float value;

        char sep;
        vec.push_back(std::vector<float>());
        while (split >> value) //
        {
            /*
            if(!first)
            {
                // Each new value read on line 1 should create a new inner vector
                vec.push_back(std::vector<float>());
            }
            */

            vec[col].push_back(value);

            /* ++col; */

            // read past the separator
            split>>sep;
        }

        // Finished reading line 1 and creating as many inner
        // vectors as required
        /* first = true; */
        ++col;
    }
}
```

}

this code may work well